# Surface integral of vector field $F(x,y,z)=xz\hat{i}+x\hat{j}+y\hat{k}$ where S is hemisphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm stuck on this problem.  I've looked up a bunch of answers and watched youtube videos on solving similar problems, but when I try to apply what I learn to the below problem I get a weird answer (
$0$).

The problem I'm solving asks:

Evaluate the surface integral $\int\int_S{F{\rm d}S}$ for the vector field $F(x,y,z)=xz\hat{i}+x\hat{j}+y\hat{k}$ where $S$ is the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25, y\geq0$ , oriented in the direction of the positive $y$-axis.

Here is where I am so far:

1. Parameterize $F(x,y,z)$ in spherical coordinates and find $n\cdot {\rm d}S$:
   $$r(\phi,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}5\sin\phi \cos\theta\\ 5\sin\phi \sin\theta\\ 5\cos\phi\end{pmatrix}$$
   $$r_\phi =\begin{pmatrix}5\cos\phi \cos\theta\\ 5\cos\phi \sin\theta\\ -5\sin\phi\end{pmatrix}$$
   $$r_\theta =\begin{pmatrix}-5\sin\phi \sin\theta\\ 5\sin\phi \cos\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
   $$r_\phi \times r_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}25\sin^2\phi \cos\theta\\ 25\sin^2\phi \sin\theta\\ 25\sin\phi \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}$$
   $$0\leq \phi \leq \pi$$
   $$0\leq \theta \leq \pi$$
2. Plug into equation for the surface integral:

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\begin{pmatrix}25\sin\phi \cos\phi \cos\theta\\ 5\sin\phi \cos\theta\\ 5\sin\phi \sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}25\sin^2\phi \cos\theta\\ 25\sin^2\phi \sin\theta\\ 25\sin\phi \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}{\rm d}\phi {\rm d}\theta$$
$$=\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi \left(625\sin^3\phi \cos\phi \cos^2\theta + 125\sin^3\phi \cos\theta \sin\theta + 125\sin^2\phi \cos\phi \sin\theta \right){\rm d}\phi {\rm d}\theta$$

3. Evaluate:

inner integral:

$$= \frac{625}{4}\sin^4\phi \cos^2\theta + 125\left(\frac{\cos^3\phi}{3}-\cos\phi\right)\cos\theta \sin\theta + \frac{125}{3}\sin^3\phi \sin\theta \vert_0^\pi$$
$$=\frac{500}{3}\left(\cos\theta \sin\theta\right)$$

outer integral:

$$= \frac{500}{6}\sin^2\theta \vert_0^\pi$$
$$=0$$

This definitely seems wrong.  :/

Comment: I adjoined the surface to the disk $x^2 + z^2 = 5, y = 0$ applied the divergence theorem, and also get 0.

Comment: oh really?  I guess I just need to build up mathematical confidence.  Thank you!

Comment: Doug's way is nice. On that disk the normal is a multiple of $\hat k$, but the $\hat k$ component of $F$ vanishes on that disk, so the dot product is automatically zero there.